# variable not keeping cached value after manipulation?

Tags: jquery

this is probably beginner question. I put an element to variable but it seems it is changing after manipulation later in code.

```js
$('#toggle-links a').click(function() {

var prnt = $(this).parent();
var xxx = prnt.prev();
console.log(xxx);

prnt.prev().toggleClass('_hidden');
var yyy = $(this).parent().prev();

if (xxx.hasClass('_hidden')) {
    console.log(yyy);
    console.log('aa');
} else {
    console.log(xxx);
    console.log('bb');
}   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" class="abc">
</div>
<div id="toggle-links"><a>click</a></div>
```

After clicking link, I would expect that (after I manipulate element by toggling class) checking if xxx has class would return false, since I cached element first. Instead the condition evaluates as true. What I am missing here? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "I cached element first", all you did was point a variable (xxx) at it. Then you point another variable (yyy) at it. Then you toggle the class in the element. Both xxx and yyy will offer back the same altered element. The variables are pointers to, not copies of, the parent, because you are referencing a compound object:

*Javascript has 5 data types that are passed by value: Boolean, null, undefined, String, and Number. We’ll call these primitive types. Javascript has 3 data types that are passed by reference: Array, Function, and Object. These are all technically Objects, so we’ll refer to them collectively as Objects*

(https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0)

What you need to make a copy of the element is jQuery's .clone() - so:

```
var xxx = prnt.prev().clone();
```

Then you can change the element without affecting xxx.